# Mounting AWS EBS into CoreOS

Tags: amazon-ec2, coreos

I have launched an EC2 instance with 100Gb EBS as https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-ec2.html docs.

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: media-ephemeral.mount
      command: start
      content: |
        [Mount]
        What=/dev/xvdb
        Where=/media/ephemeral
        Type=ext4
    - name: format-ephemeral.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Formats the ephemeral drive
        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        RemainAfterExit=yes
        ExecStart=/usr/sbin/wipefs -f /dev/xvdb
        ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mkfs.btrfs -f /dev/xvdb
    - name: var-lib-docker.mount
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Mount ephemeral to /var/lib/docker
        Requires=format-ephemeral.service
        After=format-ephemeral.service
        Before=docker.service
        [Mount]
        What=/dev/xvdb
        Where=/var/lib/docker
        Type=btrfs
```

if i run the above, the EBS is mounted correctly, but on system reboot, the volume is is not persistent

using

```
storage:
  filesystems:
    - name: ephemeral1
      mount:
        device: /dev/xvdb
        format: ext4
        wipe_filesystem: true
systemd:
  units:
    - name: media-ephemeral.mount
      enable: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Before=local-fs.target
        [Mount]
        What=/dev/xvdb
        Where=/media/ephemeral
        Type=ext4
        [Install]
        WantedBy=local-fs.target
    - name: var-lib-docker.mount
      enable: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Mount ephemeral to /var/lib/docker
        Before=local-fs.target
        [Mount]
        What=/dev/xvdb
        Where=/var/lib/docker
        Type=ext4
        [Install]
        WantedBy=local-fs.target
    - name: docker.service
      dropins:
        - name: 10-wait-docker.conf
          contents: |
            [Unit]
            After=var-lib-docker.mount
            Requires=var-lib-docker.mount
```

as per docs, i get

```
core@ip-10-1-2-188 ~ $ sudo /usr/bin/coreos-cloudinit --from-file storage1.conf
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Checking availability of "local-file"
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Fetching user-data from datasource of type "local-file"
2019/01/15 17:09:28 line 2: warning: unrecognized key "storage"
2019/01/15 17:09:28 line 9: warning: unrecognized key "systemd"
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Fetching meta-data from datasource of type "local-file"
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Parsing user-data as cloud-config
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Merging cloud-config from meta-data and user-data
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Updated /etc/environment
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Ensuring runtime unit file "etcd.service" is unmasked
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Ensuring runtime unit file "etcd2.service" is unmasked
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Ensuring runtime unit file "fleet.service" is unmasked
2019/01/15 17:09:28 Ensuring runtime unit file "locksmithd.service" is unmasked

core@ip-10-1-2-188 ~ $ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Container Linux by CoreOS"
ID=coreos
VERSION=1967.3.0
VERSION_ID=1967.3.0
BUILD_ID=2019-01-08-0044
PRETTY_NAME="Container Linux by CoreOS 1967.3.0 (Rhyolite)"
ANSI_COLOR="38;5;75"
HOME_URL="https://coreos.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://issues.coreos.com"
COREOS_BOARD="amd64-usr"
```

What is the correct way to mount the EBS volume on CoreOS?

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed a step.  [cloud-configs have been deprecated for quite some time now.  You correctly converted that cloud-config into a [container linux config](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/migrating-to-clcs.html) (CLC) file, but missed using [config transpiler](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/overview-of-ct.html) (CT) to then render an ignition sequence.  You can check this by running your config through the [online validator](https://coreos.com/validate/).  After running that CLC config through the config transpiler I get the following, which validates correctly:

```
{
  "ignition": {
    "config": {},
    "timeouts": {},
    "version": "2.1.0"
  },
  "networkd": {},
  "passwd": {},
  "storage": {
    "filesystems": [
      {
        "mount": {
          "device": "/dev/xvdb",
          "format": "ext4",
          "wipeFilesystem": true
        },
        "name": "ephemeral1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "systemd": {
    "units": [
      {
        "contents": "[Unit]\nBefore=local-fs.target\n[Mount]\nWhat=/dev/xvdb\nWhere=/media/ephemeral\nType=ext4\n[Install]\nWantedBy=local-fs.target\n",
        "enable": true,
        "name": "media-ephemeral.mount"
      },
      {
        "contents": "[Unit]\nDescription=Mount ephemeral to /var/lib/docker\nBefore=local-fs.target\n[Mount]\nWhat=/dev/xvdb\nWhere=/var/lib/docker\nType=ext4\n[Install]\nWantedBy=local-fs.target\n",
        "enable": true,
        "name": "var-lib-docker.mount"
      },
      {
        "dropins": [
          {
            "contents": "[Unit]\nAfter=var-lib-docker.mount\nRequires=var-lib-docker.mount\n",
            "name": "10-wait-docker.conf"
          }
        ],
        "name": "docker.service"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Additionally, it's important to note that [there are other differences as well](https://coreos.com/ignition/docs/latest/what-is-ignition.html#ignition-vs-coreos-cloudinit) between `ignition` and `coreos-cloud-init`.  The most important of which is that *ignition only runs once*.  Thus, for things like wiping the contents of that ephemeral disk, you should not expect `wipe_filesystem: true` to be run every single boot.

Try booting the machine with this config instead.  You should get the expected results.

Comment: I would need to compile https://github.com/coreos/container-linux-config-transpiler/ onto the EC2 image as the `ct` command is not available, in this case.

Thanks